# Is difference in Standard Deviation a useful metric to report?

Tags: inference, standard-deviation, reporting

Below is part of a report comparing two items, A and B. The goal is high readability. People with little statistical knowledge needs to be able to read this report and quickly understand key differences between the two datasets.

1. Statistically insignificant items were reported as "Same"
2. Statistically significant items **but not practically significant** were listed as "< 5PSI"
3. For other items I have listed, I have reported the average difference. ie +15 implies unit A statistically 15PSI on average higher than unit B.

Does it make sense to report difference in standard deviation or is there a better method? For example, if the mean difference is +36 and the standard deviation is 12 and 15 for one cell. I'll report the standard deviation as -20%, so:

> +36:-20%

[image]